# If user inputs start and end date, how to write a query to get the date between these dates in golang

Tags: sql, go

In my html page, user clicks on Download button after entering the start and end date to download data in csv format.
I have used jquery to get the user inputs from the screen and pass the values to `main.go`
Now in `main.go`, I am trying to run a select query to read all the data in database between the two dates that is coming from jquery.
Something like below:

```
func adminPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    dsn := "server=eccdb1677.md3q.ford.com;user id=prx_mdesk_appl;password=******"

    db, err := sql.Open("mssql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    r.ParseForm()
    StartDate := r.FormValue("startdate")
    EndDate := r.FormValue("enddate")
    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM mdesk.dbo.tbl_fdbk WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate")

    for rows.Next() {
        var (
            CDSID      string
            CreateDate int
            Rating     int
            Comments   string
        )

        err = rows.Scan(&CDSID, &CreateDate, &Rating, &Comments)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
        }
        file, err := os.Create("reports.csv")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()

        w := csv.NewWriter(file)
        err = w.WriteAll(rows)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Error writing record to csv:", err)
        }
    }

}
```

This code has error in so many levels, but right now I'm focusing more on how to write the select query to read the data between start date and end date.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"This code has error in so many levels..."_ :D Brilliant.

Comment: Parse the values with [`time.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse), then do the obvious: `db.Query("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN $1 and $2", t1, t2)`. Dates are no different from strings or numbers as far as the sql package is concerned.